# Enclosing prepared statement placeholders in single quotes

Tags: php, escaping, mysqli, prepared-statement

When creating a prepared statement in `mysqli`, should I enclose string value placeholders in single quotes?

I.e. should I write:

```
 INSERT INTO Person (Name) VALUES ('?')
```

or

```
 INSERT INTO Person (Name) VALUES (?)
```

Comment: Related PDO question [PDO Update not replacing the placeholders in a prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11332987/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Person (Name) VALUES (?)
```

will work perfectly